# Why does a pause reset after enabling full screen mode?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-video

I'm trying to add a video player, I'm using `react-native-video-controls` to add controls on my video but it has a problem with resetting a pause

[image]

**code:**

```
handleExitFullScreen = () => {
    this.setState({
        fullScreen : false
    });
}

handleEnterFullscreen = () => {
    this.setState({
        fullScreen : true
    });
}
<VideoPlayer
          source            = {{ uri: link }}
          disableVolume
          disableBack
          onEnterFullscreen = {this.handleEnterFullscreen}
          onExitFullscreen  = {this.handleExitFullScreen}
          toggleResizeModeOnFullscreen = {false}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `react-native-video-controls module`,

```js
    _toggleFullscreen() {
        let state = this.state;

        state.isFullscreen = ! state.isFullscreen;

        if (this.props.toggleResizeModeOnFullscreen) {
            state.resizeMode = state.isFullscreen === true ? 'cover' : 'contain';
        }

        if (state.isFullscreen) {
            typeof this.events.onEnterFullscreen === 'function' && this.events.onEnterFullscreen();
        }
        else {
            typeof this.events.onExitFullscreen === 'function' && this.events.onExitFullscreen();
        }

        this.setState( state );
    }
```

you can see that it executes `setSate` when changing the status of the screen. That means being rendered again.

The implementations are included in such renderers as react-native-dom, react-native.

Looking at the [`setState` implementation](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/ce43a8cd07c355647922480977b46713bd51883e/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L58-L67) in `React.Component`, everything was delegated to act on the renderer that created the component instance.

```js
// A bit simplified

setState(partialState, callback) {
    // Use the 'updater' field to talk back to the renderer!
    this.updater.enqueueSetState(this, partialState, callback);
};
```

This is how `this.setState()` is defined in the `React` package, but it is how `DOM` is updated.
Read `this.updater` set by `React DOM`, allow `ReactDOM` schedule, and process updates.

Comment: thank you for your helpful, but i solved the issue by adding an attribute 'paused' to VideoPlayer component